# What happened to the blacklist option in the App Console

Tags: google-app-engine

This used to show the top users of the app during the previous hour, reset on the hour.

Now it does not show anything.
It was useful for detecting DOS or broken software making requests in a loop.

Then you could move an IP to a dos list.

Answer (score 1):

Now you have to define your own blacklist in a dos.yaml or dos.xml file before you see anything.

Go to https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/general#blacklists

Check the last section on the page to see how to make this file for whichever platform you're using(python, java or GO).